# Is it possible to get the metadata for all result sets from SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to get metadata for all result sets returned by Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server 2016, using [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-for-object-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

But it is only returning metadata for first result set. If I have an SP which is returning data by two select statements (hence two result sets), is there any way possible to extract metadata for all result sets.

Comment: *"But it is only returning metadata for first result set."* The hint is in the name. ;)

Comment: Sure. I just mentioned this for illustration purpose only. I need similar output with multiple result sets. :) ... May be with some other command/technique.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-for-object-for-multiple-result-sets

Comment: Thanks @AlexK., this is what I was looking for. I think I have to play with C# code trick.